# Ant Throws Reference Error for Existing Jar File

Tags: ant

I want to add task to my build.xml file:

```
<target name="forbidden-checks" depends="download-forbidden-checks">
    <taskdef name="forbidden-apis" classname="de.thetaphi.forbiddenapis.AntTask"
             classpathref="lib/forbiddenapis-2.2.jar"/>
    <fa:forbiddenapis classpathref="build.classpath" dir="${build.dir}" targetVersion="${jdk.version}">
        <bundledsignatures name="jdk-unsafe"/>
        <bundledsignatures name="jdk-deprecated"/>
        <bundledsignatures name="jdk-non-portable"/>
    </fa:forbiddenapis>
</target>
```

I see that jar is downloaded, there is no problem. However I get an error:

```
download-forbidden-checks:

setup-maven-url:

download-via-maven:
      [get] Getting: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/thetaphi/forbiddenapis/2.2/forbiddenapis-2.2.jar
      [get] To: /home/kamaci/pro/lib/forbiddenapis-2.2.jar

forbidden-checks:

BUILD FAILED
/home/kamaci/pro/build.xml:2391: Reference /home/kamaci/pro/lib/forbiddenapis-2.2.jar not found.
```

I checked if I have a problem with the path of jar. So, I've put forbiddenapis-2.2.jar to another place than the project. I've pointed that jar from my taskef but I got same error.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

I've changed it to that:

```
<target name="forbidden-checks" depends="download-forbidden-checks">
    <taskdef name="forbidden-apis" classname="de.thetaphi.forbiddenapis.AntTask">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="/home/kamaci/pro/forbiddenapis-2.2.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <fa:forbiddenapis targetVersion="${jdk.version}">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="lib/forbiddenapis-2.2.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <bundledsignatures name="jdk-unsafe"/>
        <bundledsignatures name="jdk-deprecated"/>
        <bundledsignatures name="jdk-non-portable"/>
    </fa:forbiddenapis>
</target>
```

However, it didn't work:

```
Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:de.thetaphi.forbiddenapis:forbiddenapis
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/home/kamaci/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

When I run this:

```
ant forbidden-checks -lib lib/
```

it works. My project definition starts with that at build.xml:

Why I should add -lib? Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the issue is the `classpathref` as it is using a literal value and not a path element, so the jar may exist just not on the classpath, try creating a path element to use for the [taskdef](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/typedef.html)

```
<path id="lib.path">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
</path>

<taskdef name="forbidden-apis" classname="de.thetaphi.forbiddenapis.AntTask"
         classpathref="lib.path"/>
```

or defining the classpath inside the taskdef.

```
<taskdef name="forbidden-apis" classname="de.thetaphi.forbiddenapis.AntTask">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="lib/forbiddenapis-2.2.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```